# LibGdx Scrollpane Images

Tags: image, libgdx, scrollpane

I was trying to use a Scrollpane filled with images. But the images don't keep their original size but their were stretched in the x-axis. I tried to solve this by setting the size manually but anything did work. Hopefully someone of you have an idea how to solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance.